# How to detect if browser/user is able to pay using GOOGLE PAY?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to check if a clients web-browser does support GOOGLE PAY.

I know this works on Apple Pay (scripts can be found anywhere online). It is not necessary to check if any payment methodes are available, I just would like to detect the "ability" (if google pay has been installed)

Here is a script I am using, but it always return TRUE, even if no payment-option is given at google. This code sample comes from google developers website.
The problem is, it ALWAYS returns TRUE as long as the browser is able to load the js ... but I would like to know if the user already has payment methodes accepted via google pay. The option (existingPaymentMethodRequired: true) has no effect.

```
<script async
      src="https://pay.google.com/gp/p/js/pay.js"
      onload="onGooglePayLoaded()">
      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
      let googlePayClient;
    function onGooglePayLoaded() {
      googlePayClient = new google.payments.api.PaymentsClient({
        environment: 'TEST'
      });
      const baseCardPaymentMethod = {
      type: 'CARD',
      parameters: {
        allowedCardNetworks: ['VISA','MASTERCARD'],
        
        allowedAuthMethods: ['PAN_ONLY','CRYPTOGRAM_3DS']
      }
    };
    
    const googlePayBaseConfiguration = {
      apiVersion: 2,
      apiVersionMinor: 0,
      allowedPaymentMethods: [baseCardPaymentMethod],
      existingPaymentMethodRequired: true
    }
      googlePayClient.isReadyToPay(googlePayBaseConfiguration)
      .then(function(response) {
        if(response.result) {
          var xx = response.result.toString();
          alert(xx);
        } else {
          alert("Unable to pay using Google Pay");
        }
      }).catch(function(err) {
        console.error("Error determining readiness to use Google Pay: ", err);
      });
      
    }
    
    </script>
```

any ideas?

Comment: I came across the same issue. Any updates to your problem that may help me?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you are using TEST environment:

```
environment: 'TEST'
```

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects):

> Note: In the TEST environment, if you set existingPaymentMethodRequired to true in an IsReadyToPay() request, the response always returns true.

You have to use PRODUCTION environment.

Comment: It is worth noting that using the PRODUCTION environment requires the merchantInfo to also be set.